# Download entire website directory structure, without downloading any file contents

Tags: linux, wget, web

Need to download the entire website tree structure with directory/files names, but without download files - just structure.

like this:

```
www.example.com
 |
  dir1
   | file1.txt
     file2.txt

  dir2
   | file3.txt
   | file4.txt
```

When I use `wget --mirror` it downloas files

```
wget --mirror  http://www.example.com
```

Comment: Aside from images and other embedded media, you need to download all the websites anyway, to look for links, in order to download the rest of the page. Http has no functionality for "list all files". Wget just explores all links it can reach from the websites it downloads. So, you are not saving any time by not saving these files that you've downloaded anyways. You would be saving space.

Comment: and you could regain that space by running `find ./www.example.com/ -type f -exec truncate {} +` if you needed to.